# Getting power to Nest Thermostat E from 24V AC transformer

Tags: wiring, thermostat-c-wire

My baseboard hot water system lacks a C wire connecting the transformer at the boiler to the thermostats for any of the zones. I cannot readily run additional wiring between the transformer and the thermostats. Can I use a 24V transformer plugged into the nearby outlet to power the thermostats?

Comment: How many wires are run between the transformer and the thermostats at this time?

Comment: There are 5 wires at the thermostat but apparently the wiring from each thermostat is joined to a common wire in the attic. Thus a separate wire runs from the junction in the attic to each thermostat and the common wire runs down to the furnace.

Comment: Can you post photos of all the wiring junctions involved?

Comment: Unfortunately it's under insulation in a difficult spot to reach.